# How to define button value in popup?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I've create a VBScript [popup](http://ss64.com/vb/popup.html) with OK and Cancel buttons. How do I value the OK button?

Basically I want :

```
If OK button = True Then
  ' statement
Else

End If
```

I've tried to declare `intbutton= 1`, then

```
intbutton = objshell.popup"..."
```

but I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error because in VBScript (and VBA and VB6) all `Function` calls must use parenthesis when capturing return values (unlike `Sub` calls which must not use parenthesis unless you're using `Call` syntax - yes, I think VBScript's syntax is dumb).

You're also missing the other parameters to the function: `nSecondsToWait`, `strTitle`, and `nType`. Note that those additional parameters are optional, so leave nothing in the `nSecondsToWait` parameter space.

VBScript has built-in constants for the arguments you're wanting, they are:

```
vbOK
vbOKCancel
vbAbortRetryIgnore
vbYesNoCancel
vbYesNo
vbRetryCancel
```

You can use them like so:

```
Dim result
result = shell.Popup( "Mesage text goes here", , "Window title", vbOKCancel )
If result = vbOK Then
    ' something here
End If
```

Comment: Ah! Well I had nSecondsToWait, strTitle, and nType.  I just didn't mentioned it. What I didn't have what the understanding on how create a if statement. Thought it was different then vb.net for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: @Bond Thanks! I've amended my answer